# How to produce random numbers so that their sum is equal to given number?

Tags: c++, algorithm, random, sum, max

I want to produce X random numbers, each from the interval `<0; Y>` (given `Y` as a maximum of each number), but there is restriction that the sum of these numbers must be equal to `Z`.

Example:
5 Randoms numbers, each max 6 and the sum must be equal to 14, e.g: `0, 2, 6, 4, 2`

Is there already a C/C++ function that could do something like that?

Personally I couldn't come up with more than some ugly if-else-constucts.

Comment: Maybe using a `std::uniform_int_distribution`, keeping track of the limits for remaining numbers, and finishing it off with `std::shuffle` so the first ones aren't any more special than the last.

Comment: @chris He doesn't care about repeats, judging by his example output

Comment: @BWG, Repeats weren't accounted for. The limit tracking is in case you get, say, 6 6 to start.

Comment: @chris They weren't accounted for. Because he doesn't care. So what if he gets 6-6 to start? It generates a random sequence, so 6-6 is an acceptable start. His question mentions nothing of distribution patterns.

Comment: Out of pure curiosity... what is the context of this problem? Why is the sum of these numbers in this random sequence important?

Comment: @chris Sorry. I see now, thanks to LihO. Despite multiple re-readings, I misinterpreted his question. And thought that he meant each individual value had a max and a min, not the sum. Actually his question is oddly worded, which is probably why that happened.

Comment: @BWG, Oops, I didn't realize 0 was valid, despite clearly seeing the example. So it's better than what I thought it was, but still somewhat necessary.

Comment: @BWG: In the absence of mention of distribution patterns, it's quite reasonable for chris to offer an approach that provides what might well be intuitively expected: that the first numbers aren't more likely to be high numbers than the last (given "low" Z).

Comment: @chris Well, it is a really open ended question. For example, the first one could be within the range, and then the rest could be zero. His program could simply be `rand()%(max-min-1)+1` for the first element, and zero for the rest. I think I'm gonna downvote the question, because it is poorly worded and too open ended.

Comment: @LihO it's a small tool for a game where you have 5 lines you can invest points into, each at a maximum of 6 points and you have a total of 14 points.

Comment: @chris each number has a maximum of 6 and a minimum of 0. But the sum of all has to be 14 (for example)

Comment: does it have to be 14, or no more than 14?

Comment: @AlexBrown it has to be 14

Comment: What do you mean by random?  which distribution, or would random selection without repetition be OK?

Comment: @user2685786 In that case you may want to update your question, since you say a "maximum of Z". Sounds like you mean the total must be "exactly Z".

Comment: Well, my approach is naive, but should work similarly enough for being exactly 14. Another possibility is looping 14 times and incrementing one of the five lines each time, adjusting to four lines or below to choose from when one becomes maxed.

Comment: @Matt you're right, I'll edit the title

Comment: @chris awesome, exactly what I need! Simple and elegant (well, at least for a beginner like me ^^')

Comment: Note that the numbers cannot be 'random' under the constraints you give.  For instance, the value of the Xth number is completely fixed (it's 14 minus the sum so far), and the previous numbers may also be constrained.

Comment: @AlexBrown: That's rather pointless: the last number isn't special, so by that logic all are not random. The point is that the _set_ is random. And that's quite well defined. There's an exact number N(X,Y,Z) of solutions. A perfect algorithm has a chance of 1/N of producing each set.

Comment: stack overflow isn't here to do your homework.

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't need the generated sequence to be uniform, this could be one of the possible solutions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>

int irand(int min, int max) {
    return ((double)rand() / ((double)RAND_MAX + 1.0)) * (max - min + 1) + min;
}

int main()
{
    int COUNT = 5,    // X
        MAX_VAL = 6,  // Y
        MAX_SUM = 14; // Z

    std::vector<int> buckets(COUNT, 0);
    srand(time(0));
    int remaining = MAX_SUM;
    while (remaining > 0)
    {
        int rndBucketIdx = irand(0, COUNT-1);
        if (buckets[rndBucketIdx] == MAX_VAL)
            continue;                       // this bucket is already full
        buckets[rndBucketIdx]++;
        remaining--;
    }

    std::cout << "Printing sequence: "; 
    for (size_t i = 0; i < COUNT; ++i)
        std::cout << buckets[i] << ' ';
}
```

which just simply divides the total sum to bunch of buckets until it's gone :)

Example of output: `Printing sequence: 4 4 1 0 5`

Comment: This is bad random. as for following test: COUNT 5, MAX_VAL 5000 MAX_SUM 5000. You program always outp numbers near 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 this is a bad random.

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: this solution was written when the question specified a "MAX SUM" parameter, implying a sum of less than that amount was equally acceptable.  The question's now been edited based on the OP's comment that they meant the cumulative sum must actually hit that target.  I'm **not** going to update this answer, but clearly it could trivially discard lesser totals at the last level of recursion.

This solution does a one-time population of a `vector<vector<int>>` with all the possible combinations of numbers solving the input criterion, then each time a new solution is wanted it picks one of those at random and shuffles the numbers into a random order (thereby picking a permutation of the combination).

It's a bit heavy weight - perhaps not suitable for the actual use that you mentioned after I'd started writing it ;-P - but it produces an ***even-weighted distribution***, and you can easily do things like guarantee a combination won't be returned again until all other combinations have been returned (with a supporting shuffled vector of indices into the combinations).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using std::min;
using std::max;
using std::vector;

// print solutions...    
void p(const vector<vector<int>>& vvi)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < vvi.size(); ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < vvi[i].size(); ++j)
            std::cout << vvi[i][j] << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}

// populate results with solutions...
void f(vector<vector<int>>& results, int n, int max_each, int max_total)
{
    if (n == 0) return;
    if (results.size() == 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= min(max_each, max_total); ++i)
             results.push_back(vector<int>(2, i));
        f(results, n - 1, max_each, max_total);
        return;
    }

    vector<vector<int>> new_results;

    for (int r = 0; r < results.size(); ++r)
    {
        int previous = *(results[r].rbegin() + 1);
        int current_total = results[r].back();
        int remaining = max_total - current_total;
        for (int i = 0; i <= min(previous,min(max_each, remaining)); ++i)
        {
            vector<int> v = results[r];
            v.back() = i;
            v.push_back(current_total + i);
            new_results.push_back(v);
        }
    }
    results = new_results;
    f(results, n - 1, max_each, max_total);
}

const vector<int>& once(vector<vector<int>>& solutions)
{
    int which = std::rand() % solutions.size();
    vector<int>& v = solutions[which];
    std::random_shuffle(v.begin(), v.end() - 1);
    return v;
}

int main()
{
    vector<vector<int>> solutions;
    f(solutions, 5, 6, 14);
    std::cout << "All solution combinations...\n";
    p(solutions);
    std::cout << "------------------\n";
    std::cout << "A few sample permutations...\n";
    for (int n = 1; n <= 100; ++n)
    {
        const vector<int>& o = once(solutions);
        for (int i = 0; i < o.size() - 1; ++i)
            std::cout << o[i] << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm just imagining running this with `X=1,000,000 Y=1,000,000 Z=1,000,000,000` =)  I'll let you know when my thought experiment finishes the initial-population step.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include <cstdlib> //rand ()
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    int random ,x=5;
    int max , totalMax=0 , sum=0;
    cout<<"Enter the total maximum number : ";
    cin>>totalMax;
    cout<<"Enter the maximum number: ";
    cin>>max;
    srand(0);
    for( int i=0; i<x ; i++)
    {

        random=rand()%max+1; //range from 0 to max
        sum+=random;
        if(sum>=totalMax)
        {
            sum-=random;
            i--;
        }
        else
        cout<<random<<' ';
    }
    cout<<endl<<"Reached total maximum number "<<totalMax<<endl; 


}
```

I wrote this simple code
I tested it using totalMax=14 and max=3 and it worked with me 
hope it's what you asked for

Comment: There is no guarantee this algorithm will terminate in an acceptable amount of time.  Also, it gives an unfair weighting to numbers that appear earlier in the sequence (by always accepting them), thereby biasing the distribution.

Comment: i agree with you that i shouldn't accept all the numbers before testing them

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  There is no guarantee that the sequence will add up to a specific value, and that's what the OP asked for.

Comment: There's in fact a guarantee it won't add up to the specific value, because it backtracks in case `sum == totalMax`.

Answer (score 0):

LiHo's answer looks pretty similar to my second suggestion, so I'll leave that, but here's an example of the first. It could probably be improved, but it shouldn't have any tragic bugs. [Here's a live sample.](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qrq48cr9G)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <random>

std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd());

constexpr int MAX = 14;
constexpr int LINES = 5;

int sum{};
int maxNum = 6;
int minNum{};

std::array<int, LINES> nums;

for (int i = 0; i < LINES; ++i) {
    maxNum = std::min(maxNum, MAX - sum);

    // e.g., after 0 0, min is 2 because only 12/14 can be filled after
    int maxAfterThis = maxNum * (LINES - i - 1);
    minNum = std::min(maxNum, std::max(minNum, MAX - sum - maxAfterThis));
    
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(minNum, maxNum);
    int num = dist(gen);
    
    nums[i] = num;
    sum += num;
}

std::shuffle(std::begin(nums), std::end(nums), gen);
```

Creating that ditribution every time could potentially slow it down (I don't know), but the range has to go in the constructor, and I'm not one to say how well distributed these numbers are. However, the logic is pretty simple. Aside from that, it uses the nice, shiny C++11 `<random>` header.

We just make sure no remaining number goes over `MAX` (14) and that `MAX` is reached by the end. `minNum` is the odd part, and that's due to how it progresses. It starts at zero and works its way up as needed (the second part to `std::max` is figuring out what would be needed if we got 6s for the rest), but we can't let it surpass `maxNum`. I'm open to a simpler method of calculating `minNum` if it exists.

Comment: This unfortunately generates a very skewed distribution. Try running MAX=50, LINES=8, maxNum=100 thousands of times to see what I'm talking about.

Comment: @AlbertoSchiabel, Thanks for pointing that out. Nothing good immediately comes to mind for fixing that (after taking some time to figure out the Q&A again), but I did spot and fix a "tragic bug", which is pretty funny.

Comment: Actually, by pure coincidence, I got into a discussion over [reservoir sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling). It feels to me like this solution could potentially be adapted with those techniques to produce an unbiased result. I can't say for sure, but it feels like a problem reduction is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know how many numbers you need, generate them from the given distribution but without further conditions, store them, compute the actual sum, and scale them all up/down to get the desired sum.

Comment: Hi Victor, could you please elaborate with an example?